# Making xml file not readable by user

Tags: c#-4.0

I am  preparing  a program to price engineering projects , and i need to save each project data in a XML file,but i want this file not readable by user . is there a way to do this ?

Comment: What does "not readable by user" mean? Are you asking for ROT13 (please don't)? You can't do any better than that.

Comment: If you want to hide the data, you could encrypt it.  If you just want to make it difficult for the Average Joe, make your own binary format.

Comment: I mean encrypt the file dat to be not readable by the user

Comment: @user2976549: That doesn't make any sense.  If your program can decrypt the file, the user can also decrypt the file.

Comment: @ SLaks  let me explain my question more, what is happen when you try to open  a word file by notepad?? , I know that is a binary file , but can the user edit this file by notepad ?? .so i ask if there is a way to make my program data file give the same like word or excel program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out C# library called **System.Security.Cryptography.Xml**

Edit: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905246/how-to-encrypt-decrypt-an-xml-file) post also seems nice.

Comment: This does not help at all.  No possible key can help against a user on the same machine.