# C# encrypt whole XML File

Tags: c#, xml, encryption, xml-serialization

I already have a solution for encrypting of several XML nodes or strings.
But of course, you can open the local saved XML file and you should see the node tags. For some intelligent people it could be a reference for hidden informations.

**Is there any way to encrypt and decrypt the whole xml content including all node tags?**

Comment: you can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086049/c-encrypt-an-xml-file

Comment: That only encrypts the node data, doesn't it? I already did that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already know how to a encrypt a node, you can encrypt the root node which would be equivalent of encrypting the whole XML.

Comment: hmm... ok, maybe I explained that the wrong way. I just encrypted the node content without its tags.

Answer (score 3):

If you consider an XML as a simple string, you can just convert it to string and do the encryption of that string. ON the other side they just decrypt it and that's it!

How about that? :)

Or, to make things more juicy, you can encrypt all nodes, and then encrypt XML string that contains encrypted nodes.