# Datagridview, Show editable decrypted string.

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, datagridview, cryptography

I can show an encrypted value decrypted in a datagridview using the CellFormatting event to decrypt. But how to make this editable, such that entering a new string will encrypt it to the bound property, and still show it as written(decrypted).. ? As soon as I finish editing the cell and leave, it gives an exception in the Decrypt method.

> FormatException: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array.

```
    public static string DecryptData(string stringToDecrypt)
    {
        byte[] decryptedData = ProtectedData.Unprotect(Convert.FromBase64String(stringToDecrypt), Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(EntropyValue), DataProtectionScope.LocalMachine);
        return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(decryptedData);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code you use to encrypt data?

Comment: I'm using the code from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4017634/445533

Answer (score 0):

The exception you are getting comes most probably from the part:

```
Convert.FromBase64String(stringToDecrypt)
```

`stringToDecrypt` [must](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx) have a length that is a multiple of 4. Check that it is the case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are always decrypting the field as you load the grid, so you just need to encrypt it to save the change to the database?

Hook into the [cellValidating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidating.aspx) or similar event to see if there was a change and if there is encrypt -> save to database -> then refresh/reload grid from database.

When you reload you are bringing over the newly base64 encoded version of the field, which will then nicely decrypt, avoiding that error

Comment: Indeed. This works fine as long as I finish the edit by clicking the mouse somewhere outside. However if hitting enter, it fails with mentioned exception..

Comment: then can you use CellEndEdit instead? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellendedit.aspx ?

Comment: It was very error prone, it worked, but still through exeptions, I think because formatting event is called multiple times during editing. Decided to hide this decrypt/encrypt logic in the business layer. Makes more sense I think.