# how i can encrypt a whole xml file by c#

Tags: c#, xml, encryption

in my project i write tow method to encrypt and decrypt string some string in my xml file 
but know i want to encrypt a whole  xml file

i want to edit  methods to encrypt and decrypt a whole file Instead of string

```
  public static string Encrypt(string plainText)
          {
                byte[] initVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("teto1620@#$%asdf");
                byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
                byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("_+)&qwer9512popo");
                RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();
                symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                ICryptoTransform encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes);
                MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
                cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                byte[] cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                memoryStream.Close();
                cryptoStream.Close();
                string cipherText = Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes);
                return cipherText;
          }
          public static string Decrypt(string cipherText)
          {
                byte[] initVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("teto1620@#$%asdf");
                byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
                byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("_+)&qwer9512popo");
                RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();
                symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                ICryptoTransform decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes);
                MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes);
                CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
                byte[] plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];
                int decryptedByteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
                memoryStream.Close();
                cryptoStream.Close();
                string plainText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount);
                return plainText;
          }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017534/c-sharp-encrypt-xml-file

Comment: @ShreeKhanal unfortunately the answers in that question are sub-optimal, and it has been designated a duplicate itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`File.ReadAllText()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext.aspx) returns a string so you can just `ReadAllText()` encrypt using your normal string method, and then use `File.WriteAllText()` to write the encrypted version back to file.

*For large files however*, you can read and process line by line instead. e.g.

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("xmlfile.txt")) 
{
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
    {
         File.WriteAllText("mynewxmfile.xml", MyEncryptMethod(line));
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't do this if your have a large XML file though.

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple, Convert your XML to string and pass it to encrypt/decrypt function.
What classes are you using to create XML ? iF You are using XMLDocument, then following function could be used to convert your XML to string

```
public string ConvertToString(XmlDocument xml)
{
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    XmlTextWriter tx = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
    xml.WriteTo(tx);
    string str = sw.ToString(); 
    return str;
}
```

Similarly you could while decrypting, you could convert your decrypted string to XML as following

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(decruptString);
```

Comment: This would be an option in case the XML file is known to be small. Note that you must take care of the character encoding of the resulting `string`.