# Encrypting a file appends the last

Tags: c#, .net, xml, encryption

My objective is to obfuscate an XML configuration file so that the user will not be able to edit it. I use the following code:

```
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(this));

        SymmetricAlgorithm symmetricAlgorithm = DES.Create();
        symmetricAlgorithm.Key = new byte[8] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
        symmetricAlgorithm.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

        using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(filename))
        {
            using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fs, symmetricAlgorithm.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                xs.Serialize(cryptoStream, this);
            }
        }
```

Most of the time it works fine. But once in a while, when writing the file it would add the last few lines (211 bytes in the latest case) at the end of the file. The decryption still works fine, but it will no longer deserialize into an XML file.

EDIT:
This only happens when I delete one of my parameters and save the configuration. It is as if the serializer write some stuff at the end to keep the file the same size.

Comment: Why do you serialize the Stream again? Maybe you could write it directly to the disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem with a different approach, as suggested here, used a DeflateStream instead of CryptoStream:
[c# encrypt xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017534/c-sharp-encrypt-xml-file)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [EncryptedXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.encryptedxml.aspx) instead and let the Framework worry about encryption/decryption.

Comment: I like it, unfortunately I am using .NET 4.0.

Comment: @Serge `ExcryptedXml` is available from .NET 2.0 upwards.

Answer (score 1):

Empty the file before opening it for writing. Check the remarks section of the [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openwrite.aspx).