# Reading Network Credentials from an XML file to connect to a TFS Server

Tags: c#, xml

How to read Username and Password from an xml file to connect to the TFS Server using `UICredentialsProvider();`? Such that the `Windows Network Credentials` would not need to prompt but instead reads the credentials in the xml file and automatically connects the user.

I tried this but is not working:

```
    NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(username, password, tfsServer);
    XmlUrlResolver resolver = new XmlUrlResolver();
    resolver.Credentials = nc;
```

XML:

```
<Connect>
    <TfsServer>http://sample:8080</TfsServer> 
    <Username>FirstName</Username>
    <Password>SecretPassword</Password>
</Connect>
```

Also, is there a way to encrypt the password in the XML file? Like it would be unreadable?

Comment: For encrypting xml file take a look on [C# Encrypt an XML File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086049/c-sharp-encrypt-an-xml-file)

Comment: Thanks. How would this work with a user's perspective? If there is a c# method for encryption, will it change the text of the password field into an encrypted text? My desired result would be that the XML password field is unreadable...

Answer (score 0):

You can parse xml with LINQ to XML:

```
var connect = XElement.Load(path_to_xml);
string tfsServer = (string)connect.Element("TfsServer");
string username = (string)connect.Element("Username");
string password = (string)connect.Element("Password");
```

Comment: Thanks. But how can I connect to TFS without the need to prompt network credentials? Just by using the tfsServer, username, password that we parse.