# How to add prefix to Signature element in C#

Tags: c#, ws-security, x509certificate2, xml-signature, signedxml

We are signing a xml elements using SignedXml class. The requirement is add signature node in Ws Security to communicate with the service.

We could able to sign the elements and verified those. In this case the xml  Sample code is as below

```
        X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(CertPath, CertPassword);

    // Create a new XML document.
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

    // Format the document to ignore white spaces.
    doc.PreserveWhitespace = false;

    // Load the passed XML file using it's name.
    doc.Load(new XmlTextReader(FileName));

    SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(doc);
    signedXml.SigningKey = certificate.PrivateKey;


    // Create a reference to be signed.
    Reference reference = new Reference();

    reference.Uri = "#" + elementID;

    // Add an enveloped transformation to the reference.
     XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform envTransform = new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
    reference.AddTransform(envTransform);

    // Add the reference to the SignedXml object.
    signedXml.AddReference(reference);



    // Create a new KeyInfo object.
    KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();

    // Load the certificate into a KeyInfoX509Data object
    // and add it to the KeyInfo object.
    keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(certificate));

    // Add the KeyInfo object to the SignedXml object.
    signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;

    // Compute the signature.
    signedXml.ComputeSignature();


    // Get the XML representation of the signature and save
    // it to an XmlElement object.
    XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();
```

by using this Signature element generated as <`signature> .... </signature>` . but we want to generate it as <`ds:signature> .... </ds:signature>`

Tried to set the prefix explicitly but then signature is not validated after.

Could you please guide how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

As this is a generic enough question, [this post might be helpful to someone looking for the same information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30813170/5286901).

For the specific project I'm working on, IRS A2A submission, it is what I used when thinking that I needed to add the prefixes to the `Signature` element.  However, in discussion with some other SO users, I have abandoned the idea of adding the prefixes to the `Signature` element as it is not actually necessary.

Comment: Thanks for this, we have tried the same thing i.e passing signature without prefix but still stuck into WS security error in .NET. Have you passed this error in .NET or any reference?